# adding multiple contents in a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am new in iphone devlpmnt.i just want to add current date in the cell. i need "notiftext" appear left of the cell and current date on the right.thanks in advance

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

AppDelegate *AppD = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

}



MLNotifMessage *list = [AppD.storage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = list.notifText;

NSString *dteStr = [[NSString alloc]init];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/London"]];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

dteStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:list.date];

[dateFormat release];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = dteStr;
return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any other style of the cell or use custom cell to fully customize the cell.  I think for your question tabel view stye `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` is enough.

```
  cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
  cell.textLabel.text = list.notifText;
  cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSDate date];
```

Comment: so by using this code date and time appears on right of the cell??

Comment: Ya.. notifyText on left of the style and date on the right of the cell.. have a look at [this](http://coding-is-kind-of-magic.blogspot.in/2012/02/uitableview-has-some-build-in-styles.html)

Comment: i need date and time to appear on right ...am sorry i didnt mentioned it on question...

Comment: See [NSDate date] will give u date along with time, You can even format that date using NSDateFormatter . First give a try and come back. And specify what format of the date and time you want.. will help u..

Comment: i've tried the code but its showing bad access error. its a push notification app

Comment: Am so sorry... i forgot to clean the project...now its working perfect thanks alot....can u give me ur mail id ??

Comment: Sure `anil.varghese@robosoftin.com` and check my [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2021193/anil) also. If ur problem solved accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

use Custom TableViewCell. You can make custom tableViewCell by subclassing it